# Java reads test source file locally, but fails to read on Bamboo server

Tags: java, bamboo

JUnit test located in  `src\test\java\irmsUtilities\General\MyTest.java` reads files from `src\test\resources​\`, such as  `src\test\resources​\MyData1.txt`.
There are two similar implementations for Windows box:

```
private String readResourceFile(String fileName) throws IOException {  // fileName = "/MyData1.TXT"​​

  StringBuilder retStr = new StringBuilder();
  URL url = this.getClass().getResource(fileName);
  InputStream is = url.openStream();
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
  String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  retStr.append(line).append("\n");  }
  return retStr.toString();
}
```

OR

```
private String readResourceFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
  StringBuilder retStr = new StringBuilder();
  fileName = "src/test/resources"+fileName;   
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
  String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    retStr.append(line).append("\n");
  }

  return retStr.toString();
}
```

Code above reads file and passes tests locally (Windows), but fail to find file on Bamboo server. 
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/test/resources/MyData1.TXT (No such file or directory)​`

How should I change IO to get test file son Bamboo as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bamboo server is running on Linux?

For Windows files src\test\resources​\MyData1.txt and src/test/resources/MyData1.TXT are the same; Linux file system is case sensitive, so MyData1.txt and MyData1.TXT are two different files.

Also, it's bad idea to hardcode EOL ("\n") for the same reason (Win vs *nix) - use System.lineSeparator() instead.